# I met an error when i using hive transform features

Tags: python, transform, hive

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: [Error 20003]: An error occurred when trying to close the Operator running your custom script.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator.close(ScriptOperator.java:486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:193)
        ... 8 more`

The HQL script as follow:

```
SELECT
  TRANSFORM (userid, movieid, rating)
  USING 'python /home/daxingyu930/test_data_mapper2.py'
  AS userid, movieid, rating
;
```

the python script is very simple, using `\t` to split lines.

I have tested the python script in Linux with follow shell script:

```
cat test_data/u_data.txt | python test_data_mapper2.py
```

Pleas give me some idea about the question, it drive me crazy and make me cant sleep.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9):

before using your custom script, you should add your scripts into distributed cache.

eg.

```
add file  /home/daxingyu930/test_data_mapper2.py;

SELECT
    TRANSFORM (userid, movieid, rating)
    USING 'python test_data_mapper2.py'
    AS userid, movieid, rating
;
```

Comment: This solved my problem competely.  I was doing everything right but for some reason in the using clause I had:  using 'python /path/to/file/mapper.py'   I was getting the metadata HiveException.  It seems that it boils down to in the using clause you cannot have the full path.

Answer (score 3):

chmod +x  test_data_mapper2.py.

then From hiveCl1 run below command 
add file  /home/daxingyu930/test_data_mapper2.py ;

Answer (score 1):

You should not give the full path to your script in USING clause. Just use the python script (.py) name.