# Hive transform using Python: Unable to initialize custom script

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to test Hive TRANSFORM by feeding a Python script as mapper. My hive script is:

```
add file  /full/path/to/mapper.py;

set mapred.job.queue.name=queue_name;

use my_database;

select transform(s.year, s.month, s.day, s.hour) 
using 'mapper.py' 
from my_table s limit 10;
```

and my Python mapper script is simply trying to echo the input:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

I have tried to run this with the following combinations:

1. Removing the `add file ...` in the hive script and providing full path to `mapper.py` in the `select ...` statement
2. Keeping the `add file ...` and the full path for mapper: `/path/to/mapper.py`
3. Keeping the `add file ...` and relative path for mapper: `./mapper.py`
4. Tried selecting mapper output using `AS` clause (`using 'mapper.py' as line`)

So far, all of the above attempts have resulted in Hive reporting that it cannot initialize my custom script:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. Unable to initialize custom script.
```

I'm not able to understand the nature of this 'initialization.' Is Hive not able to

1. *find* my script (i.e., a path issue)?
2. locate the python executable (i.e., the `#!` shebang)

I'm following the "Custom map/reduce scripts" in the [Hive tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Custommap%2Freducescripts).

Comment: You'll probably get more information by looking in the logs of the underlying MapReduce job from either your JobTracker or ResourceManager (depending on which MR version you are using).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved it by modifying my `select...` statement as

```
add file  /full/path/to/mapper.py;
select transform(s.year, s.month, s.day, s.hour) 
using ' python mapper.py' --<--- This line changed
from my_table s limit 10;
```

[Reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106127/i-met-an-error-when-i-using-hive-transform-features)